# Allow wildcards in proximity searches with multiple words

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is when i try to use wildcards inside a proximity search with multiple words.

Examples:

```
"hell* worl*"~3
```

Basically, I would like to get all the words that starts with "hell" and "worl" that are close to each other with a max distance of 3.

I do not get any error but it does not find the documents. It seems that wildcards are not analyzed. I also have set `analyze_wildcard: true`

The DOC says:

> By default, wildcards terms in a query string are not analyzed. By
>   setting this value to true, a best effort will be made to analyze
>   those as well.

But, only the following query works:

```
"hello world"~3 # this works
```

This is my query:

```
{  
   "size":15,
   "from":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "query_string":{  
                  "query":"\"hell* worl*\"~3",
                  "analyze_wildcard":true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Reference:

- [Proximity Searches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_proximity_searches)
- [Wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html) to achive what you want, though be careful cause the terms are not analyzed here.

```
{
  "size": 15,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "wildcard": {
                "t": "hell*"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "wildcard": {
                "t": "worl*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 3,
      "in_order": true
    }
  }
}
```

The problem in your `query_string` is that `*` character is not treated as wildcard within quotes. What you get is simple slop phrase similar to `"hell# worl#"~3` cause special characters have no meaning within quotes.

Be careful though, cause span queries have much slower performance than simple phrase search (though it seems that it still is [faster](https://people.apache.org/~mikemccand/lucenebench/SpanNear.html) than [slop phrases](https://people.apache.org/~mikemccand/lucenebench/SloppyPhrase.html) which actually surprised me).

Better option if you can still prepare your data for the scenario is to use ngrams. With ngrams simple `"hell worl"~3` would match what you want.